# Reload tree. do something after reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree. I need to reload it without refreshing page and then do some actions.
This code reloads tree

```
$.jstree._reference('#tree').refresh(-1);
```

But how can I specify actions after tree is reloaded?

**Edited**

Did not find another way. I have just put needed code into reselect function.

```
bind("reselect.jstree", function (event, data) { 
    // code here
     })
```

this function is triggered after refresh. Are there another ways to do this?